# phonegap developer app stay in downloading status

Tags: phonegap, phonegap-developer-app

I install Phonegap on my system and on my android phone.But when I want to connect to app by my mobile , app stay in downloading...
*I checked my ip and port and there are correct.
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you include whitelist plugin? Can you edit your question and show us your config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

i find the problem. my firewall was active and dont allow to connect.
for solve you should right click on Anti-virus and disable firewall.